# Disable the "background activity" notification in GNOME when opening Flatpak applications

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome-shell, flatpak

This sort of thing started happening a while back; I thought it was going to go away (because it's super annoying), but after a couple of system updates, it looks like it's here to stay.

[image]

As far as I can tell it's only happening with Flatpak'ed applications, so looks like there is something new in the lifecycle for those applications that changed (not so) recently. It's worth to note that if I check the `Portals` settings, they don't have the "run in background" enabled — which make things "more interesting".

As always, there should be a way to mute these, without entirely muting the notifications at the system level.

> I'm running `Arch Linux`, but I see this happens as well for Flatpak'ed applications running in `Ubuntu` and `Fedora` VMs — using `Boxes`.

So my question is simple: is there a way to fix this somehow? I think disabling/muting this type of notifications, even for each single application, may hide a problem — now or in the future, so I would like to avoid that route.

Answer (score 2):

I was also extremely annoyed by these notifications (for me it's in KDE tho), but today I found out I can just click on "Learn more" and allow the app to run in the background. From that point on, I don't get this notification for that specific app anymore. Repeat that for all apps and you're good to go.

That is for KDE, at least. I don't see a "Learn more" button in your screenshot, so maybe just clicking the notification will bring the popup up.
Still, I hope this helps.